# how to make spring boot rest api as stateful

Tags: java, rest, spring-boot, javabeans, stateful

I want to make web application with REST and spring boot. Rest web service is stateless. I want to make it stateful so that the information server send to client after first request should be used in upcoming request. Or the execution done in first or second request will be used further. 
Can we generate some session id for this and this session id client can send to sever in followed requests ? If yes, then 
if state is changing (values get modified due to some manipulation) of some objects/beans. So how can we save the state inorder of objects/beans to make it stateful and  what is the scope of these beans (whose value will be modified) and those classes/beans which will give call to these beans as multiple clients or users will be using this web application ?

Comment: Could you please be more explicit with your question? and provide some example that you has taken.

Comment: nit: if it's stateful, then by definition it's not REST.

Comment: @JonathanJohx - I have not written any code, I am still working on design. First part of my question is, can we make rest api using spring-boot as stateful? May be by creating some session-id or token, which can be used by client in different/further call to my web api?

Comment: It's OK, thank you. So I'm agree with @Krease.

Answer (score 4):

Restful API's are not stateful by design, if you make them stateful using a server side then its not REST!

What you need a correlation Id which is a recognised pattern in a distributed system design. Correlation Id will let you tie requests together.

Answer (score 3):

Sessions are typically an optimization to improve performance when running multiple servers. They improve performance by ensuring that a clients requests always get sent to the same server which has cached the clients data.

If you only want to run a single server, you won't have to worry about sessions. There are two common approaches to solve this problem.

### 1. In Memory State

If the state you want to maintain is small enough to fit into memory, and you don't mind losing it in the event of a server crash or reboot, you can save it in memory. You can create a spring service which holds a data structure. Then you can inject that service into your controllers and change the state in your http handlers.

Services are singletons by default. So state stored in a service is accessible to all controllers, components, and user requests. A small pseudo example is bellow.

#### Service Class

```
@Service
public class MyState
{
  private Map<String, Integer> sums = new HashMap<>();

  public synchronized int get(String key) {
    return sums.get(key);
  }

  public synchronized void add(String key, int val) {
    int sum = 0;

    if (sums.contains(key)) {
      sum = sum.get(key);
    }

    sum += val;

    sums.put(key, (Integer)sum);
  }
}
```

#### Controller Class

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/sum")
public class FactoryController
{
  @Autowired
  private MyState myState;

  @PostMapping(consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
  @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
  @ResponseBody
  public SuccessResponse saveFactory(@RequestBody KeyVal keyVal)
  {
    myState.add(keyVal.getKey(), keyVal.getValue());
  }
}
```

**Note:** This approach will not work if you are running multiple servers behind a load balancer, unless you use a more complex solution like a distributed cache. Sessions can be used to optimize performance in this case.

### 2. Database

The other option is to just use a database to store your state. This way you won't lose data if you crash or reboot. Spring supports the hibernate persistence framework and you can run a database like Postgres.

**Note:** If you are running multiple servers you will need a more complex solution since hibernate caches data in memory. You will have to plug hibernate into a distributed cache to synchronize in memory state across multiple servers. Sessions could be used as a performance optimization here.

### Important

Whenever you are modifying state you need to make sure you are doing it in a thread safe manner, otherwise your state may be incorrect.